# ¿Como relacionar mi base de datos para que un empleado pueda también realizar una compra?

Tags: base-de-datos

Estoy Realizando un sistema de faturacion , pero no se como hacer que un empleado , tambien  pueda realizar una compra como cliente, tengo la siguiente base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que pasaría si un empleado quisiera reaizar una compra , que debo hacer para que eso sea posible? , debo de crear una tabla empleado y relacionarla con persona?

Comment: ¿Tienes una tabla `Persona`, otra `Cliente` y otra `Empleado` o cómo tienes organizadas las cosas?

Comment: hasta el momento solo tengo la tabla **Persona** como se muestra en la foto de mi pregunta

Comment: Mira si [esta respuesta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31198) te puede ayudar. Me parece acertado ese modelo: una tabla `persona` con los atributos comunes a los empleados y a los clientes. Luego una tabla `cliente` con los atributos que tienen los clientes y no los empleados y una tabla `empleado` con lo que un cliente no tiene. Luego te puedes valer de `rol` para identificar quién es empleado, quien es cliente y quien es ambas cosas. Ten en cuenta que posiblemente un empleado tendrá derecho a ciertos descuentos especiales cuando compre y eso hay que gestionarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías añadir una tabla intermedia entre persona y rol, que permita a las personas desempeñar varios roles, y dejar de usar el campo Rol_Codigo de persona.

En el modelo ER que modelaría todo esto, tendrías que crear una relación entre dos entidades. En su momento se definió la cardinalidad como 1:N, se propagó y por eso hemos llegado a este punto. Afortunadamente la solución es sencilla. Intenta hacer lo que te describo, modifica tu pregunta con el código que utilices para arreglarlo y, si no te sale, te ayudo ampliando mi respuesta. No te olvides de adjuntar el SQL con la estructura de tu base de datos con algunos registros de ejemplo para hacer pruebas.

Suerte con ello.

Comment: buenas , me quieres decir que entre **Persona** y **Rol** Cree tabla que los una , es decir , como si la cardinalidad entre  **Persona** y **Rol** fuera de muchos a muchos y en la mitad estari la tabla intermedia la cual llevaria como llaves primarias la llaves de **Persona** y **Rol**?

Comment: ¡Exacto! Cardinalidad N:N, una persona puede ser empleado y cliente (N roles), y un rol puede ser asignado a N personas. Y ten en cuenta lo que te comenta A. Cedano, me parece muy acertado para atributos que no sean comunes. Con utilizar rol para determinar los roles, ya no tanto: supongo que en rol tienes los nombres de los roles, así que mejor esta tabla intermedia. Ya me cuentas.

Comment: Si te ha resultado útil, recuerda votar y aceptar la respuesta :) https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers